# regexp_replace in VS CODE

Tags: php, regex, visual-studio-code

everyone, I'm looking for tips&tricks how to do something like regexp_replace in **VS code**. I have huge amount of .php files in my project. Where language text are stored in multidimensional array() as i.e.: `$lang['admin']['configuration_updated']` and I need to change it all to function `getLangText('admin','configuration_updated')`

I tried with regex `\$lang\[(.)*\]\[(.)*\]` but it replace all text. How to replace just part of string?

I need regex for VS code, not PHP function.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a non greedy pattern to match the content inside brackets:

```
\$lang\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]
```

Then replace with:

```
getLangText($1, $2)
```

### Demo